# Share container definition in multiple docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose there is a nginx proxy container definition:

```
nginx-proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

I would like to define this container in multiple docker-compose.yml file (one per project).

How can I do that, without stopping each time the container (because is using the port 80)? The idea is: if there are no `nginx-proxy` containers running, run this, otherwise use the running one.

Comment: Are you using the Compose v2 spec?

Comment: Yes. ...[Writing unuseful chars to go]...

Comment: I think you will will need a script. Something like: ping or check your nginx using port 80, if it isn`t up, run docker-compose run nginx-proxy to create one.

Comment: hi! any answers to this question ?

Comment: You should use solution from [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113957/running-multiple-projects-using-docker-which-each-runs-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score -1):

You can have one nginx for all your projects. In that case you need to have only_nginx/docker-compose.yml file where you have ] nginx service and use

```
projectx_service:
    extends:
        file: /path_to/only_nginx/docker-compose.yml
        service: nginx-proxy
    ...
```

this kind of block in your every project docker-compose files.

Example:

**only_nginx/docker-compose.yml** :

```
nginx-proxy:
image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
ports:
    - "80:80"
volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

**project1/docker-compose.yml**

```
project1_service:
    extends:
        file: /path_to/only_nginx/docker-compose.yml
        service: nginx-proxy
    ...
```

**project2/docker-compose.yml**

```
project2_service:
    extends:
        file: /path_to/only_nginx/docker-compose.yml
        service: nginx-proxy
    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the original problem, but just avoid duplication of code.

If I run `docker-compose up` on both projects, first is ok, second always tell me "... Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated".

Moreover, the `extends` keyword is deprecated in Docker Compose v3